# Question about assuming the existence of an object.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, continuity

I know that for $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f$ is cont. if and only if for any sequence $\{x_n\}_{n \ge 1} $ that converges to $z$, we have
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_n) = f(z).$$

In a proof where I have to demonstrate that $f$ is continuous, I have to assume that there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n \ge 1}$ that converges to $z$.

Question: In this case, am I also allowed to assume that
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_n)  $$
exists in my proof?

Thank you.

Comment: You need implication $x_n\to z \Rightarrow f(x_n) \to f(z)$ for appropriate $x_n$.

Comment: The answer to your question is no.  You need to prove that limit exists (and is equal to $f(z)$).  For many functions and sequences that will be relatively easy.  For example, if both your sequence and the function are monotonic and the function is bounded "near" $z$, the limit must exist.

Comment: No.  You may not assume the limit exist.  Part of the proof will involve proving that indeed a limit does exist.   (FWIW, assuming that the limit exists wouldn't do you much good anyway if you didn't know what it converges to.  Part of proving a limit exist *is* proving that that there *is* a specific value it converges to.)

Comment: " I have to assume that there exists a sequence {xn}n≥1 that converges to z"  You don't have to *assume* it.  You *DO* know for a fact for *every* $z$ there will *always* be sequences that converge to it.  That's a fundimental principal of real and complex numbers.  For example, let $x_n = z + \frac 1n$.  THen $x_n \to z$.  Or let $x_n =z$.  Then $x_n \to z$.... of let $x_n = \sqrt[n]2 \times z$ .... or .....

Comment: @fleablood 'FWIW, assuming that the limit exists wouldn't do you much good anyway' --> well then it looks like OP is just checking to see if proving the existence of limit is part of the game? i mean it's like the usual definition of continuity at a point: it should be $f(a)$ defined, $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ exists AND THEN existence equals defined limit. i have a feeling the definition given to OP in the 1st place was unclear. do you disagree?

Comment: good observation with the $x_n \to z$. sounds very axiom of choice kinda thing. but there's no need to assume it. you can prove it: Choose $x_n = 5 = z$ for all $n$.

Comment: We tend to forget how confusing first breaking into mathematics is in that we are now expected to accept nothing and prove and develop everything. I think the OP has a point that we have a proof of continuity and we start with "Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence converging to $z$" and the student may well wonder "Why do we assume such a sequence exist?" That was actually part of the definition of what the real numbers are but that was probably just mentioned briefly so a student wouldn't even notice. Meanwhile the instructor assumes it is so obvious we don't understand the student's issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me first clarify a point about starting the proof. You wrote:

> "I have to assume that there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n \ge 1}$ that converges to $z$".

But that is not a good wording of how to start the proof, the word "exists" should not be there. Instead you should word it like this:

> "I assume that $\{x_n\}_{n \ge 1}$ is a sequence that converges to $z$."

And now you must prove:

> "$\{f(x_n)\}_{n \ge 1}$ converges to $f(z)$."

In doing this you are *not* allowed to assume that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n)$ exists.

Instead, what you must prove is *that limit exists* **and** *is equal to $f(z)$*.

However, it's not like you actually have to prove two different things. Any valid proof of the statement "$\{f(x_n)\}_{n \ge 1}$ converges to $f(z)$" will allow you to conclude that the limit exists and is equal to $f(z)$.

In particular, that's exactly what you may conclude if you do a proof by applying the actual $\epsilon,N$ definition of convergence:

> $\{f(x_n)\}_{n \ge 1}$ converges to $f(z)$ if and only if for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N$ such that if $n \ge N$ then $|f(x_n) - f(L)| < \epsilon$.

Comment: To emphasize the pedagogical point, I'd start the proof with "I assume that $\{ x_n \}_{n \geq 1}$ is an *arbitrary* sequence that converges to $z$."

Comment: I think maybe the OP is feeling a bit doubtful that for a given $z$, that he/she actually *knows* that there *are* sequences that converge to $z$.  But there must be as, for example $x_n = z$ is a sequence that converges to $z$.  As is $x_n = z - \frac 1n$.  As is $x_{0} = 0$ and $x_{n+1} = \frac {x_n + z}2$... and so on.  We *DO* take it as a given that for every $z$ infinitely many sequences $\{x_n\}$ so that $x_n\to z$ *do* exist.  The trick is to prove that for an *arbitrary* such sequence, we *will* have $f(x_n)\to f(z)$.

Comment: @fleablood thank you for clearing that up.